# Need to replace lastName and orders value with xxxx. I get the following object. How can I do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
"uri": {  
  "protocol": "https:",  
  "slashes": true,  
  "auth": null, 
  "search": "?lastName=PRFTWENTYEIGHT",  
  "query": "lastName=PRFTWENTYEIGHT", 
  "pathname": "/v2/purchase/orders/6142144",  
  "path": "/v2/purchase/orders/6142144?lastName=PRFTWENTYEIGHT",  
  "href": "https://v2/purchase/orders/6142144?lastName=PRFTWENTYEIGHT" 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to give more details about your problem and show any code you tried by yourself. Also, you are a Developer (look your nick), so please format the code text ;)

Comment: I am trying to mask the personal information for security reasons, I have tried the following code so far.                                                                                   
 ``` import { is } from 'ramda';

import * as log from './logging';

const maskSensitiveInfo = [
  'lastName',
  'firstName',
  'orderId',
  'ffToken',
  'cardNumber',
  'address',
  'number',
  'ffId',
  'username',
  'application_name',
  'client_id',
  'prevOrder'
];

Comment: export default function mask(obj, propsList = maskSensitiveInfo) {
  let maskedObj;
  try {
    // deep clone `obj` before mask it
    maskedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    if (!is(Object, maskedObj)) return maskedObj;
    Object.keys(maskedObj).forEach(key => {
      maskSensitiveInfo.includes(key)
        ? (maskedObj[key] = 'xxxx')
        : (maskedObj[key] = mask(maskedObj[key], propsList));
    });
    return maskedObj;
  } catch (err) {
    log.info('Mask sensitive info error: ', err);
  }
  return obj;
}

Comment: Using this mask() in different file from where the info are coming. As I am having various object in different format so I have tried this, but this is not working for the above mentioned object. I think I need to try Regex and I am very new developer and does not know how to use regex to mask those information. Any one can help me in ti please?

Comment: ```function mask(obj, propsList = maskSensitiveInfo) { let maskedObj; try { // deep clone obj before mask it maskedObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); if (!is(Object, maskedObj)) return maskedObj; Object.keys(maskedObj).forEach(key => { maskSensitiveInfo.includes(key) ? (maskedObj[key] = 'xxxx') : (maskedObj[key] = mask(maskedObj[key], propsList)); }); return maskedObj; } catch (err) { log.info('Mask sensitive info error: ', err); } return obj; } ```

Comment: How to format codes here?